# Ruby equivalent of C# string.Format

Tags: c#, ruby, string-formatting

I have an array of values and I would like to print it in some format. In C# I would do

```
string.Format(" {0} | {1} _ {2}!", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
```

resulting in an output such as

```
" 10 | 20 _ 30!"
```

How to achieve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for using [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) ?

```
array=[11,13,14]
" %s | %s _ %s!" % [array[0],array[1],array[2]]
# => " 11 | 13 _ 14!"
array=[0,13,14]
" %s | %s _ %s!" % array
# => " 0 | 13 _ 14!"
```

Comment: Thank you, also works. Is there a way how to effortlessly print space character when there is a value 0 in the array?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I didn't catch you

Comment: Imagine that array[0] stores a value of 0 and I would like to see "   | 13 _ 14" instead of " 0 | 13 _ 14"

Comment: You can do array.collect!{ |x| x == 0 ? " " : x } then any do any of the mentioned answers to format your string

Comment: I accepted your answer because you provided that solution with [*array] which is indeed nice.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek `[*array]` is redundant. It unpacks the array into... another array. Just do `% array`

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby it should be

```
" #{array[0]} | #{array[1]} _ #{array[2]}!"
```